# How to add custom JavaScript file on printJS

Tags: javascript, printjs

I have a script for printing the receipt and it works perfectly fine as well as the CSS file

```
printJS({printable:'print-receipt', type:'html',css:'assets/css/receipt.css'});
```

But, when I try to add a JavaScript file with this following code *i.e:* `javascript:'charts/charts.min.js'`  and it should look like this

```
printJS({printable:'print-receipt', type:'html',css:'assets/css/receipt.css',javascript:'charts/charts.min.js'});
```

Then, there is no effect after the javascript file is added! Is there any way to add a javascript file on **printJS** ?  Please, I need your help. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation page (https://printjs.crabbly.com/) there's no argument **javascript** that's why it doesn't work.

Since the **printable** argument works with html as well, i suggest you to create that element first.

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<!-- This is the library of chartjs -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

and in js make sure you select the chart element

```js
printJS({printable:'chart', type:'html'});
```

this is the sample implementation : https://jsfiddle.net/oak8Ljd6/